# Несколько ip в файле hosts с одинаковым dns именем

Tags: linux, ip, dns, hosts

Возможно ли на сервере linux в файле hosts прописать 2 разных ip адреса с одним и тем же dns именем? А так же хотелось бы уточнить как происходит чтение файла hosts? Или как можно организовать правильное обращение сервиса по dns имени, с расчетом того, что ip адресов может быть несколько?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

да, конечно, одно и то же имя можно употреблять в файле `/etc/hosts` многократно. безразлично: в одной строке или в разных.

возвращены будут результаты для первого найденного совпадения.

p.s. возвращать разные результаты dns-запросов умеют специализированные программы: [dns-серверы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80).

Comment: Все понятно, благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, запись будет в виде:

```
10.10.25.221 onebfront01-test
192.168.0.10 onebfront01-test
10.10.25.222 onebfront02-test
192.168.0.11 onebfront02-test
10.10.25.225 onebfront03-test
192.168.0.12 onebfront03-test
```

Тем самым, мы назначаем на один FQDN несколько IP адресов.
P.S. указывать несколько IP адресов в одной строке будет неправильно.